# R ggplot grouping and plotting multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello everyone i am having a problem with grouping my data and plotting it further in `ggplot()`. My data consists of few columns, which 4 first ones (all together) correspond to the "sample ID", the other two which is Zeit(Time in seconds) and Temp.

I need to plot Time vs Temp plot for each of the sample, however to group it by their ID is very chalenging and at the moment i cannot figure it out.

Sample data:

```
> dput(sampledata)
structure(list(a = c(703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 
                        703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 
                        703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 703210L, 
                        703210L), b = c(3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 
                                            3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 
                                            3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L, 3988L), c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
                                            ), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                          4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L),  Zeit = c(0L, 240L, 300L, 420L, 540L, 546L, 
                                                                                                                                           0L, 180L, 300L, 360L, 540L, 546L, 0L, 180L, 300L, 360L, 540L, 
                                                                                                                                           545L, 0L, 120L), Temp = c(913L, 675L, 570L, 514L, 515L, 355L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     867L, 687L, 575L, 543L, 518L, 437L, 874L, 690L, 577L, 562L, 529L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     455L, 856L, 721L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Zeit", "Temp"), row.names = 2317:2336, class = "data.frame")
```

The same data, but in format which i can explain exactly what i meant by 4 columns defining the sample ID:

```
          a    b c d Zeit Temp
2317 703210 3988 1 1    0  913
2318 703210 3988 1 1  240  675
2319 703210 3988 1 1  300  570
2320 703210 3988 1 1  420  514
2321 703210 3988 1 1  540  515
2322 703210 3988 1 1  546  355 
2323 703210 3988 1 3    0  867#here starts the new sample (d=3)
2324 703210 3988 1 3  180  687
2325 703210 3988 1 3  300  575
2326 703210 3988 1 3  360  543
2327 703210 3988 1 3  540  518
2328 703210 3988 1 3  546  437
2329 703210 3988 2 4    0  874#here starts the new sample (c=2)
2330 703210 3988 2 4  180  690
2331 703210 3988 2 4  300  577
2332 703210 3988 2 4  360  562
2333 703210 3988 2 4  540  529
2334 703210 3988 2 4  545  455
2335 703210 3988 3 5    0  856#here starts the new sample (c=3 & d=5)
2336 703210 3988 3 5  120  721
```

and so on...It as well happens that a & b changes, so **together all those 4 columns define the sample ID**

I tried to plot it in `ggplot()` easily:

```
ggplot(sampledata, aes(x=Zeit, y=Temp)) + geom_line(size=1.5) #however it was total chaos
```

Than i tried to use `interaction()`:

```
ggplot(sampledata, aes(x=Zeit, y=Temp, group=interaction(a,b,c,d))) + geom_line(size=1.5)
```

as well i got the plot which was very chaotic...

Anyone has an idea how i can plot it?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: may be you can create additionall colunm which concate your 4 colunm into one ID colunm? (`paste`)

Comment: hey, i have just tried that, and still is chaotic. the problem is when i `group` it by a new column in `ggplot`, the time gets mixed up, instead of each plot curve starting from 0 (as 0 seconds), all get together mixed and make no sense

Comment: Try to show pictures what you get and what want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a id variable in your data set and then give color as id in plot. Below is the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
sampledata <- data.table(sampledata)
sampledata[, id:=paste(a,b,c,d, sep="_")]

ggplot(sampledata, aes(x=Zeit, y=Temp, color=id)) + geom_line(size=1.5)
```

With color argument, you can see different samples clearly. Hope this helps. :)